# Iterate Through a Non-Sequential Range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to iterate through a non-sequential range.  In another words, skipping certain indexes/elements based on user input like so.

```
>>> 0
>>> 3
>>> 4
>>> 6
>>> 7
>>> 8
>>> 9
```

I couldn't figure out how so I attempted this method.

```
import re

>>> crazyrange = '0, 3-4, 6, 7-9'    # User input string
>>> crazyrange = re.split (', ', crazyrange)
>>> crazyrange
['0', '3-4', '6', '7-9']
>>>
>>> masterlist = []
>>> def get_range (values):
    rangelist = []
    for i in range (int (values [0]), int (values [1]) + 1):
        rangelist.append (i)
    return rangelist
>>>
>>> for i in crazyrange:
    if '-' in i:
        values = i.split ('-')
        masterlist.extend (get_range (values))
    else:
        masterlist.append (int (i))
>>>
>>> masterlist
[0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You're pretty much creating a list of entries based on user input.  You've decided what types of input will be allowed and created parsers for that input.  The only thing left is to handle errors when the input doesn't fit your criteria.  There probably is a "better" way to do it, but why?

Comment: Off topic: Any particular reason you're using `re.split (', ', crazyrange)` and not just `crazyrange.split(', ')`?

Comment: That was my first attempt but it didn't work because I had the wrong syntax so I jumped to re.split.  It works now.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks pretty good, but you don't need `re` and you could tidy it up a bit by using python's `range` function and `yield`ing the items from a generator function:

```
crazyrange = '0, 3-4, 6, 7-9'    # User input string

def get_range(range_string):
    items = range_string.replace(" ", "").split(",")
    for i in items:
        if '-' in i:
            start, end = i.split('-')
            for j in range(int(start), int(end)+1): # range() is not inclusive
                yield j
        else:
            yield int(i)

for x in get_range(crazyrange):
    print x

print list(get_range(crazyrange))
# [0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

There's also an option without explicit loops:

```
crazyrange = '0, 3-4, 6, 7-9'    # User input string
import itertools
items = [i.split("-") for i in crazyrange.split(", ")]
range_list = [range(int(i[0]), int(i[-1])+1) for i in items]
print list(itertools.chain(*range_list))
```

Or this option may be the simplest:

```
crazyrange = '0, 3-4, 6, 7-9'    # User input string

def get_range(item):
    pair = item.split('-')  # may only be one item, but that's OK
    return range(int(pair[0]), int(pair[-1])+1)

items = crazyrange.split(', ')
print [i for item in items for i in get_range(item)]
# [0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Very clean and simple.  I was hoping to avoid double for loop in general but you saved the day with generator.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I added a couple more options that may be simpler, but I don't think there's any way to avoid the nested loops. You can make the inner loop implicit via `itertools.chain`, but that seems to be less readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the same output within less code using `list comprehension`:

```
crazyrange = '0, 3-4, 6, 7-9'

ranges = [range(int(k.split("-")[0]), int(k.split("-")[-1]) +1) for k in crazyrange.split(',')]

print(ranges)
print([j for k in ranges for j in k])
```

Output:

```
[range(0, 1), range(3, 5), range(6, 7), range(7, 10)]
[0, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Thanks!  Less code indeed but I'll have to go with Matthias's answer for readability and for using generator.  Plus, it's much simpler for me to process the range list without going through a double looped list comprehension.  I also up voted your solution as a token of appreciation.

Comment: Thanks. But you can modify `ranges = [...]` to `ranges = (...)` and you'll have a generator that you can use to have your data. Also, you're right, list comprehension may seem little complicated but they are very powerful when you use them more often. And like what i said, you can use this solution if you prefer writing your code within less lignes, which python can handle it smoothly.